# How to use User.IsInRole() in an HTML string?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-identity

I have an MVC5 project and there is some menu being shown/hidden according to the roles of users. On the other hand, I use DataGrid and some icons for Details, Update and Delete operations via an HTML string and need to implement User.IsInRole() in this HTML string. How can I do that?

**View (Razor):**

```
<script>
var table;

$(document).ready(function () {

table = $('#dtbStudent')
    .DataTable({

    //code omitted for brevity

    "columnDefs": [
    {
        "targets": 6,
        "data": "download_link",
        "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {

        return '<a title="Details" id="lnkStudentDetails"></a>' +
               '<a title="Edit" id="lnkStudentEdit" ></a>' +
                '<a title="Delete" id="lnkStudentDelete" ></i></a>';
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });

    });


    //EventListener ################################################

    $(document).on('click', '#lnkStudentDetails', function () { 

        //!!! It is also possible for me to check the roles at here 
            and return false & tooltip message  

        //opens Details modal
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#lnkStudentEdit', function () {
        //opens Edit modal
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#lnkStudentDelete', function () {
        //opens Delete modal
    });

    //###############################################################

</script>
```

Comment: Why is this code within curly braces? Why is there a `return` statement? Why are the HTML strings wrapped in single quotes? What does "not working" mean? Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve], emphasis on complete. I think in your effort to provide brevity, you accidentally removed too much context.

Comment: is this code inside a javascript/jquery function??

Comment: @RajshekarReddy Yes, in **jQuery Datatable**.

Comment: @ClintEastwood oh .. well it would be better if you can update your question with relevant code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you are building up a HTML string in your javascript function, In which you are using Razor syntax. In this case I suggest you to do as below.

Set the string into a **C# variable** initially.

```
@{
 string additionalString = Request.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("Admin") ? "<a title='Edit' id='lnkEdit' ></a>" : "";
}
```

you can use `if` block, I used ternary operator as its just one line within the block. With this in place you can write your **script** as

```
//what ever was here 
{
 return '<a title="Details" id="lnkDetails" ></a>' + '@additionalString' +'<a title="Delete" id="lnkDelete" ></i></a>';
}
```

Here within the `<script>` you can access the C# variable by using `@` and your variable name.

Note: don't miss the `' '` around `@additionalString`..

---

**Edit:** After you gave more details its better if you set a variable in the JavaScript which holds either `true` or `false` based on `User.IsInRole("Admin")`. To do that add this part of code into your view page.

```
@{
 string isAdmin = Request.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("Admin") ? true : false;
}
```

Now assign this to a javascript variable like

```
<script>
  var UserIsAdmin = @Html.Raw(@isAdmin); // assign C# variable to JavaScript variable.
</script>
```

With this in place you can use this variable in all your scripts.

So the changes to your code are

```
 "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {

    var renderHtml = '<a title="Details" id="lnkStudentDetails"></a>';

    if(UserIsAdmin){
      renderHtml +='<a title="Edit" id="lnkStudentEdit" ></a>';
    }

     renderHtml += '<a title="Delete" id="lnkStudentDelete" ></i></a>';
    return renderHtml;                               
   }
```

And to your event handler as

```
$(document).on('click', '#lnkStudentDetails', function () { 
    //  UserIsAdmin variable can be used to check if user is admin or not.
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried but not worked :( I also tried to build a result syring in @{ .. } field, but does not work. Any other way?

Comment: @ClintEastwood are you trying to write a Razor code inside a javascript block?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, I updated the relevant code. Please also look the **$(document).on('click', '#lnkStudentDetails', function () { ... }** field. It is also ok for me to check roles in there.

Comment: You rock!.. Many thanks for your perfect solution. Voted+